# Outlook Add-in Development : Prevent Forwarding Mail 'As Attatchment'

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, email-attachments

How to detect 'Forward As Attatchment' event in C# Outlook Add-in development.

I want to show message 'You can't forward this mail as attatchment' in message box.

Note that, This is not VSTO application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no straight scenario* or trivial way for handling such cases in Outlook. There are several ways to handle such scenario as possible workarounds.

The *first* possible solution is to handle the [MailItem.Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(even)) event which is fired when the user selects the `Forward` action for an item, or when the `Forward` method is called for the item, which is an instance of the parent object. In the event handler you may check for attached files, display a message box and cancel the action if required. To handle item-level events you may consider creating an inspector wrapper (or item-wrapper) where you could set up event handlers correctly, see [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) for more information.

The *second* possible solution is to handle the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event of the `Application` class in Outlook where you could handle all outgoing emails, not only forwarded.

The *third* solution is to repurpose the UI control which is responsible for the action in Outlook. So, you may replace the default action with your own or just prepend it with your custom logic. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Object Model does not explicitly (through its type library / interop, which can be imported for use in Visual Studio) expose the `OnForwardAsAttachment` event (only `Reply`/`ReplyAll`/`Forward` events), even though (on the `IDispatch::Invoke` level) it fires an event with dispid of `0xF618` when a user clicks "Forward as Attachment".

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes a cancelable [SafeMailItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm).`OnForwardAsAttachment` event:

```
private SafeMailItem _sItem;
private MailItem _oItem;
...
_oItem = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
_sItem = new SafeMailItem();
_sItem.Item = _oItem;
_sItem.ForwardAsAttachment += OnForwardAsAttachment;
...
private void OnForwardAsAttachment(object Forward, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MailItem newMessage = (MailItem)Forward;
    if (OlSensitivity.olConfidential == _oItem.Sensitivity)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Confidential message '{_oItem.Subject}' cannot be forwarded");
        Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        newMessage.Subject = _oItem.Subject;
        newMessage.Body = $"Please see the attached message '{_oItem.Subject}'.";
    }
}
```